# How do I center a div with an unspecified width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my code for HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head><link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
    <body>
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">
                <img src="test.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.outer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}

.inner {
    width: auto;
    margin: auto;
}

.inner > img {
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This is a simplification of the code I am using inside Bootstrap's modal.js to display images after clicking on thumbnails.

What I want is for an image to be centered on the viewport, in a responsive way - that is, the image is displayed in its true dimensions unless the viewport is smaller than one of the dimensions, in which case, the image should resize accordingly.

The `outer` div tends to have the exact dimensions of the viewport - which works well.

The image is given `width: auto; max-width: 100%;` which is very responsive to the width of the viewport, but doesn't respond to the height of the viewport. Adding a `max-height: 100%;` doesn't do anything.

Unfortunately, as it stands the `inner` div hugs the left of the viewport unless given a specific `width`.

If I add `display: table` to the `.inner`, then the div centers, but no longer responds to changes in viewport width.

So, how do I get the `inner` div to be centered and responsive to the width and height of the viewport in a way that never crops or alters the aspect ratio of the image or stretches it beyond the original dimensions of the image?

Is this impossible using only CSS and HTML (and Bootstrap) or will it require some custom JS? I don't know enough JS to confidently code this on my own, which is why I am hoping there is some sweet CSS trick that allows for this contradictory behaviour conditional on viewport size.

*Tagging Twitter's Bootstrap because I will be using this in context of Bootstrap so any solution that uses Bootstraps JS plugins is welcome.*

EDIT: To be more clear, I need to center `inner` not just the image within `inner`.

Comment: try text-align:center;

Comment: every thing considered as text

Comment: can you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with what you have?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/J77Lr/12/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wrap div around child elements based on width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175741/how-to-wrap-div-around-child-elements-based-on-width)

Comment: Because that was a different question, the answer to which was not useful given that I failed to provide relevant constraints and context in it.

This question is more specific and relevant to my problem.

Also, the question statement is an EDIT from another user, it wasn't my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this

```
.outer {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

http://jsbin.com/puyabore/1/edit

Comment: generally responsive based on width

Comment: The problem with this is that it expands `inner` to the size of the viewport, instead of moving `inner` to the center. This causes other problems, since the inner div needs to wrap around / stick to the image.

Comment: check the above code seems code working fine. i am added img-responsive class for image

Comment: Like I said above, that just centers the image inside the visible div, instead of centering the div itself. This is the result I am looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/J77Lr/12/ (Just what it looks like when the viewport is large, unfortunately `display: table` ruins all responsiveness). Hope that helps explain what I mean by centering the div.

Comment: .modal-dialog width default 600pxyour getting the problem

Comment: Nope, that gets over-ridden by width: auto in the main CSS.

Comment: @NikhilMahajan if you're using my fiddle, why not just reply to my answer in your original question with anything else you need?

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore. I have tried every combination of CSS attributes over night and concluded that it is impossible to meet my needs without the use of JS. So, I am going to work on that front.

I would close this question and the other one if I could, but I don't know how to do so.

Comment: The example I made properly responded to a bootstrap responsive image,  by either being very small for a small image or full width for a large image... yet not going above 100%. The containing div was also centered. Seems to be what you have been asking for. I made that for you in a few minutes, so I can assure you it was very possible. If you notice any specific issues, respond to my original answer and I can update it accordingly.