# Centering a layer of unspecified width

Tags: html, css

For the sake of record, I have read [How do I center a div with an unspecified width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24176531/how-do-i-center-a-div-with-an-unspecified-width) and found that although my problem is related to it, it is not exactly that.

I have a layer containing only one image (the logo of my site) and nothing else. Right now I do know the size (width) of the logo image (and hence the width of the layer) and if I specify the width of the layer, I am able to put it in the center of the page. That is:

```
#logodiv {
position:absolute;
width:200px;
margin:auto;
}
```

and inside the webpage source

```
<div id="logodiv">
<img src="logo.png" />
</div>
```

However for the sake of making my site more responsive for smaller display size devices, I do not want to specify the width of logodiv in hard and fast figures. But then I am unable to place my logo layer in the center of the page.

Any workaround for that?

Comment: Post your HTML, specifically, the elements that demonstrate the problem that you are trying to solve.  Otherwise we are guessing about what you are doing.

Comment: Edited and html code added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
#logidiv{
margin:0px auto;
display:flex;
justify-content:center
}
```

Comment: Why `margin:auto` then ?

Comment: wow! Thanks!! works like a charm. Would it work for computer and mobile devices alike?

Comment: p.s. I just found out that the margin specs aren't even required for this solution to work. Only specifying display:flex; and justify-content:center; puts the div in the center of the page.

Answer (score 1):

If your markup looks like this:

```
<div id=logodiv>
  <img src="logo.png">
</div>
```

then you can use this style

```
#logodiv {
  width:max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

to center it horizontally.

Comment: This places the layer ***very near*** the center but does not completely justify it in the middle lol. I don't know what else is required to put it dead right there.

Comment: remove spaces so markup will look like `<div id=logodiv><img src="logo.png"></div>`

Comment: OK, the div has gone to the complete left totally. As in, looking like it was set with left:0; attribute. I don't know if I am doing everything right. I must be doing something incorrectly.